# Running sparklyr Functions in Parallel

Tags: r, dplyr, sparkr, sparklyr

I am currently using sparklyr to transform a large dataset and calculate a set of metrics based on an input start and end date. This function is run on the same dataframe for multiple start and end dates to generate a number of final dataframes. This function was originally written using dplyr and parallelized using mclapply, but the data has become significantly larger so I have begun to explore spark as better alternative. This is effective for large datasets (bringing processing time down from ~8 hours to ~3 hours), but for small datasets, processing with spark has increased the time it takes mainly because I am using a for loop instead of mclapply to perform parallel runs of the code. I am wondering if there is a way to run the sparklyr function in parallel for these smaller datasets. As an example, we have the transactions dataframe below and a set of start/end dates that are run in a for loop to generate three additional dataframes:

```
transactions <- data.frame(date = c(as.Date('2022-01-01'),as.Date('2021-01-01'),as.Date('2020-01-01')),
                           transaction_value = c(10,20,10))

transactions_tbl <- copy_to(sc, transactions)

start_dates <- c(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-01-01'))
end_dates <- c(as.Date('2022-12-31'), as.Date('2022-12-31'), as.Date('2022-12-31'))

tot_val_func <- function(transactions_tbl,start_date, end_date) {
  year_tot <- transactions_tbl %>% 
    dplyr::filter(date >= start_date & date <= end_date) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(total_val = sum(transaction_value)) %>%
    dplyr::collect()
  
  return(year_tot)
}

for (i in 1:length(start_dates)) {
  total_val_func(transactions_tbl,start_dates[i],end_dates[i])
  # Dataframe exported to a data warehouse after this transformation
}
```

Would it be possible to run a parallel call of the total_val_func using sparklyr on the backend for the set of input dates, or does the function need to be run sequentially as laid out in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

According to sparklyr documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparklyr/sparklyr.pdf), you can perform cross-validation with parallelization, but I don't know if the model (function) itself is parallelized or just the cross-validation experiments.